# Windows boot option gone?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

So I have had Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu running side-by-side for the last couple of months, and both on separate hard drives. Today I turned on my computer and the option to boot into Windows was gone, but I can see the the Windows 8 hard drive, and all the data on it.

So my question is, how to I fix Grub to allow me to boot back into both Ubuntu and Windows?

By the way sorry if this is a duplicate, I searched and couldn't find anything, so if it is, just point me to the link and I will close the question.

Comment: have you tried "sudo update-grub" from a livecd yet?

Comment: Nope, do I have to use a live cd, or can I do it from Ubuntu (which I am booted into now)?

Comment: you can try from your current boot, but I've just had a higher success rate when the root volume is not on the same disk

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: Ok I'll put that in the answer box if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run "sudo update-grub" from a livecd, or from your installation if you have a livecd just in case