# Installing Ubuntu Lost Windows

Tags: 16.04, windows-7

As I was installing bunt on a system which already had Windows 7, I lost my windows 7 booting option. Now I cannot boot.
this is the RL I got after running boot-repair.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nVKKymyP3M/

How can i recover my windows?

Also posting the outpt when I run commonds like os-prober and fdisk -l

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# os-prober

/dev/sda1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain

root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1587904512 bytes, 3101376 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disklabel type: dos

Disk identifier: 0xabcc1cd3


Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type

/dev/sda1              63       2047       1985 992.5K 42 SFS

/dev/sda2  *         2048     206847     204800   100M 42 SFS

/dev/sda3          206848  524290047  524083200 249.9G 42 SFS

/dev/sda4       524290048 1953523119 1429233072 681.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.





Disk /dev/sdb: 14.7 GiB, 15724707840 bytes, 30712320 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disklabel type: dos

Disk identifier: 0x001e9453


Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type

/dev/sdb1  *     2048 30712319 30710272 14.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/497271/windows-boot-option-gone

Comment: When I try this,  it shows 'error: failed to get canonical path of 'aufs' '

Comment: Please update your question with the EXACT steps you took to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Your Boot-Repair report says: “Boot successfully repaired. You can now reboot your computer.” Have you done it? Has it helped?

Comment: I don't see an installed Ubuntu system on sda - just the installer on sdb. Please update your question to tell us *in detail* about install errors you encountered.

Comment: I am sing to Live USB to install Ubuntu. When it reached the option to select the drive, I found that Windows partition with windows 7 was jst 1 MB or so. I didnt install Ubutnu anywhere. Immediately I followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/435160/cant-boot-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

Comment: the url I posted is what I get after that

Answer (score -1):

if you made no partition when installing ubuntu, then you must have deleted windows completely so there is no other solution than reinstall windows. 
The problem is if you reinstall windows you will lose the ubuntu grub, so install windows, and then install ubuntu, when you do that there is an option that says, "install ubuntu with windows" there is where you have to say yes, then it shows you how big do you want the partition, your set it as you like, and then install it. Now it should work well.

Comment: Did you even look at http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nVKKymyP3M/

Comment: yes. but not able to understand the error. Is there any way I can point it to the correct starting address?